# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message') at click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a registration form, and it is necessary to implement the click function, when clicked, we will call the appropriate functions: login or registartion, but an Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message') at click error occurs. What is the problem?

```
const {user} = useContext(Context)
    const location = useLocation()
    const history = useHistory()
    const isLogin = location.pathname === LOGIN_ROUTE
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const click = async () => {
        try {
            let data;
            if (isLogin) {
                data = await login(email, password);
            } else {
                data = await registration(email, password);
            }
            user.setUser(user)
            user.setIsAuth(true)
            history.push(SHOP_ROUTE)
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.response.data.message)
        }

    }
```

Here are the functions login, registration

```
import {$authHost, $host} from "./index";

    export const registration = async (email, password) => {
        const response = await $host.post('api/user/registration', {email, password, role: 'ADMIN'});
        return response;
    }
    
    export const login = async (email, password) => {
        const response = await $host.post('api/user/login', {email, password});
        return response;
    }
```

Error also appears  POST https://localhost:5000/api/user/registration net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: The error is probably caused by this statement `e.response.data.message` and that is because `e` is an [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object which doesn't have a `response` property.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the cause of this error "xhr.js:220 POST https://localhost:5000/api/user/registration net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Your client side application cannot connect to the server. What causes that is not evident from the info you've provided.